# Extraer la ciudad de un texto en pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Holas tengo un gran problema y es que necesito rellanar unos campos vacios que estan en mi columna ciudad y esos vacios se encuentran en otra columna pero con el problema de que hay mucho texto adicional y solo quiero extraer del texto la CIUDAD
Ejemplo de la primera fila de la columna DESCRIPCION de mi dataframe donde se encuentra mi ciudad faltante

```
df_d = df_S[['DESCRIPCION']]
df_d.columns = ['Ciudad_sm']
df_d['Ciudad_sm'] = df_d['Ciudad_sm'].str.upper().str.strip()
df_d['Ciudad_sm']=df_d['Ciudad_sm'].str.replace('Á','A').str.replace('É','E')\
                        .str.replace('Í','I').str.replace('Ó','O').str.replace('Ú','U')

df_d['Ciudad_sm'].iloc[0]
```

la primera fila es la siguiente

[image: se resalta la ciudad que es la quiero sacar de ese texto]

```
'PLANTILLA DE DATOS\n\nFECHA Y HORA DE LA ACTIVIDAD: 20/05/2022 11:00 AM\nCLIENTE: POLLOS EL BUCANERO S.A.\nPROGRAMADA: SI\nTIPO DE SERVICIO: EMPRESAS P1\nSUBSEGMENTO: CLIENTES ESPECIALES\nCIUDAD: CORREGIMIENTO VILLA GORGONA, CANDELARIA.\nCODIGO DEL ENLACE: \tPBC0019\t\nSW DE ACCESO: AAC-VAL.CANDELARIA-M\nPUERTO: 1/5/3\nDIRECCION DEDESPLAZAMIENTO:  KM1 CALLEJON VICTOR LONGO VIA CALI-CANDELARIA, CORREGIMIENTO VILLA GORGONA, CANDELARIA, VALLE DEL CAUCA, ZIP CODE: 763579, COLOMBIA\nCONTACTO DEL CLIENTE EN SEDE: NOMBRE: DIEGO DOMINGUEZ\nTELEFONO CONTACTO CLIENTE: +573186261075\nHORARIO DE ATENCION:  L-V 12PM-13PM\nAFECTACION: DESCRIPCION ACTIVIDAD: VALIDAR EQUIPOS Y CONEXIONES\nCONTACTO DE QUIEN REPORTA: LEIDY MEIDNA\nNUMERO CONTACTO NOC: 273151-273153-273154 - 321 2738949 / 7448595 OPC 1 - 0 CLAVE 462910\n\nEQUIPOS REQUERIDOS:\n- PATCH CORD\n- PORTATIL\n- POWER METER\n- ROUTER DE PRUEBAS\n- TRV\n\nPERMISOS ESPECIALES: SI. DOCUMENTAR NOMBRE, CC, ARL, EPS\nDESCRIPCION ACTIVIDAD: VALIDAR EQUIPOS Y CONEXIONES\nIM SERVICE:I'
```

intente con un split pero no me sirve porque no todas estan de la misma manera escritas por ejemplo algunas tienen CIUDAD: pero otras solo CIUDAD

```
def get_ciudad1(string):
        seg = string.split("CIUDAD: ")
        if len(seg)==1:
                return seg[0]
        else:
                return seg[1]
```

Con esta funcion logre quitar lo que habia antes de la palabra ciudad pero no pude quitar lo que habia despues ya que lo ideal seria quitar lo que hay despues de CODIGO DE ENLACE pero no me dio de manera general pues hay unos campos que dicen CODIGO DEL ENLACE y como son tantos registros ni modo de saber como estan escritos todos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def get_ciudad2(string):
        seg = string.split(".\nCODIGO DEL ENLACE: ")
        return seg[0]

df_d['Ciudad_sm']=df_d['Ciudad_sm'].apply(get_ciudad2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria saber si todo esto se puede hacer de manera general con alguna IA o alguna otra idea porque se me ocurria sacar con un tolist() las ciudad que ya tengo en mi colunma ciudad pero sigo sin saber como buscarla o encontrar mi ciudad en la columa DESCRIPCION

```
lista_ciudades = df_sm['Ciudad'].tolist()
```

Se los agradecia si pueden ayudarme con este problema

Comment: Buen día, esta es la segunda pregunta que haces con el mismo objetivo, ten cuidado de no hacerlo ya que es considerado spam. Te recomendaría eliminar la otra pregunta ya que ésta es más completa en cuanto a la descripción del problema. Saludos

Comment: sii ya lo hice gracias por recordarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `regex` (Del inglés Regular Expresions) para extraer un `substring`

Revisando la información que enviaste es visible que el `substring` donde aparece la ciudad tiene el siguiente formato

```
\nCIUDAD: CORREGIMIENTO VILLA GORGONA, CANDELARIA.\n
```

Si te das cuenta, antes y después de la ciudad hay `\n` (Salto de línea) y eso puede servir para obtener lo que deseas.

La secuencia a identificar sería `\n(CIUDAD.*)\n`. Es decir, un salto de línea, luego debe decir "CIUDAD", obtener todos los caracteres hasta el siguiente salto de línea.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Descripción' : ['PLANTILLA DE DATOS\n\nFECHA Y HORA DE LA ACTIVIDAD: 20/05/2022 11:00 AM\nCLIENTE: POLLOS EL BUCANERO S.A.\nPROGRAMADA: SI\nTIPO DE SERVICIO: EMPRESAS P1\nSUBSEGMENTO: CLIENTES ESPECIALES\nCIUDAD: CORREGIMIENTO VILLA GORGONA, CANDELARIA.\nCODIGO DEL ENLACE: \tPBC0019\t\nSW DE ACCESO: AAC-VAL.CANDELARIA-M\nPUERTO: 1/5/3\nDIRECCION DEDESPLAZAMIENTO:  KM1 CALLEJON VICTOR LONGO VIA CALI-CANDELARIA, CORREGIMIENTO VILLA GORGONA, CANDELARIA, VALLE DEL CAUCA, ZIP CODE: 763579, COLOMBIA\nCONTACTO DEL CLIENTE EN SEDE: NOMBRE: DIEGO DOMINGUEZ\nTELEFONO CONTACTO CLIENTE: +573186261075\nHORARIO DE ATENCION:  L-V 12PM-13PM\nAFECTACION: DESCRIPCION ACTIVIDAD: VALIDAR EQUIPOS Y CONEXIONES\nCONTACTO DE QUIEN REPORTA: LEIDY MEIDNA\nNUMERO CONTACTO NOC: 273151-273153-273154 - 321 2738949 / 7448595 OPC 1 - 0 CLAVE 462910\n\nEQUIPOS REQUERIDOS:\n- PATCH CORD\n- PORTATIL\n- POWER METER\n- ROUTER DE PRUEBAS\n- TRV\n\nPERMISOS ESPECIALES: SI. DOCUMENTAR NOMBRE, CC, ARL, EPS\nDESCRIPCION ACTIVIDAD: VALIDAR EQUIPOS Y CONEXIONES\nIM SERVICE:I']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df['Ciudad'] = df['Descripción'].str.extract(r'\n(CIUDAD.*)\n')
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    Descripción                                         Ciudad
0   PLANTILLA DE DATOS\n\nFECHA Y HORA DE LA ACTIV...   CIUDAD: CORREGIMIENTO VILLA GORGONA, CANDELARIA.
```